# process toFormData from view

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I wonder if someone could answer this question for me, maybe I'm using Vue in the incorrect way here.

I'm using vue-router to link to a .vue file with a template. So I'm referencing the below code using Submit Artwork

I'm developing a form, and want to use the toFormData() function which I believe is on the Vue() instance. I cannot access the vue instance however.

At the moment my call to app.toFormData(var) or this.toFormdata(var) will produce an error "404 cannot POST" since it's failing invalid function.

How do I access this function so I can use it to parse the input form data?

```
<template>
  <div class="submitArtwork">

    <div class="container">

        <hr class="bg-info">


                  <form id="paintingForm" action="#" method="post">
                    <div class="form-group">

                      <v-text-field 
                        name="aa_name"
                        label="Name of Painting"
                        id="aa_name"
                        v-model="newPainting.aa_name"
                      ></v-text-field>

                      <v-autocomplete
                        label="Medium"
                        :items="mediums"
                        v-on:mouseover="activateHelper('mediumHelper');"
                        v-on:mouseleave="activateHelper('');"
                        v-model="newPainting.aa_medium"
                      ></v-autocomplete>

                      <v-autocomplete 
                        label="Country (optional)"
                        :items="country_list"
                        v-on:mouseover="activateHelper('countryHelper');"
                        v-on:mouseleave="activateHelper('');"
                        v-model="newPainting.aa_country"
                      ></v-autocomplete>

                      <v-autocomplete
                        label="Tags (optional)"
                        :items="tags"
                        multiple
                        v-on:mouseover="activateHelper('tagHelper');"
                        v-on:mouseleave="activateHelper('');"
                        v-model="newPainting.aa_tags"
                      ></v-autocomplete>

                      <v-file-input :rules="rules" prepend-icon="attachment" accept="image/*" multiple label="File input" @change="onFilePicker"></v-file-input>

                      <v-switch
                        v-model="consentCheck"
                        :label="`Consent: ${consentCheck.toString()}`"
                      ></v-switch>

                    </div>



                    <div class="form-group">
                      <button class="btn btn-info btn-block btn-lg" @click="showAddModal=false; addPainting();">Submit Painting</button>
                    </div>

                  </form>
...

</template>

<script>
export default {
    name: 'submitArtwork',

    data: function() { 
        return { 
      countryHelper: false,
      tagHelper: false,
      mediumHelper: false,
      newPainting: {aa_fbid: "", aa_a_firstname: "", aa_a_surname: "", aa_a_email: "", aa_country: "", aa_name: "", aa_tags: "", aa_medium: ""},
      country_list: [""],
      tags: [,
      ],
      mediums: [
      ],    
        errorMsg: false,
        successMsg: "",
        showEditModal: false,
      showAddModal: true,
      consentCheck: true,
      user: { 
        picture: { data: { url: '' } }
        }, 
      rules: [
        value => !value || value.size > 2000000 || 'Photo size should be less than 2 MB!',
      ],

    }

    }, 
  mounted() {
    showAddModal=true;
  },
  methods: {
    activateHelper(helper) {
      this.countryHelper=false
      this.tagHelper=false
      this.mediumHelper=false
      if(helper == "countryHelper") {
        this.countryHelper=true
      }
      else if(helper == "tagHelper") {
        this.tagHelper=true
      }
      else if(helper == "mediumHelper") {
        this.mediumHelper=true
      }      
    },
    addPainting() {

// ERRORS OUT HERE // ------------------------------------>
      var formData = toFormData(this.newPainting)

      axios.post("http://localhost/process.php?action=create", formData).then(function(response) {
        app.newUser = {name: "",email: "",phone: ""};
        if(response.data.error) {
            app.errorMsg = response.data.message;
        }
        else{
            app.succcessMsg = response.data.message;
            app.getAllUsers();
        }
      });
      */
    },
  } 
}
</script>

<style>
  ...
</style>
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that `toFormData` is not a method on your instance (Vue does not come with any predefined instance methods, except for lifecycle hooks). You would also have to access instance methods through `this.method()`.

Could you mean the HTML FormData API instead?
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData

Answer (score 0):

You can create a computed property and inside it prepare your form data for request. Iterate over JSON properties and add each data to form data. Or you can add ref=“form” to form and use like this: 
var formData = new FormData(this.$refs.form)